# options for creating/hosting a class library for use across applications?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, azure-devops

I need to create a class library as an API wrapper.  The library will be referenced by applications across the enterprise.  All of the projects for the enterprise are hosted on VSTS.  I'm assuming that the modern architecture approach is to host this new API wrapper class library as a NuGet package and then let each application add a reference to it.  Is this correct? Can you please provide a url reference which describes the latest and greatest way to set this up?  I'm seeing different approaches described in google search results.

Also, I think the VSTS "Package Management" extension is the preferred approach for hosting internal NuGet packages but I think there's a way to host a package on a shared network drive.  Can you please provide a url reference which describes how to do this?  Are there any caveats or pitfalls with hosting a NuGet package on a shared drive as opposed to using the VSTS "Package Management" extension?  I think the "Package Management" extension is the preferred approach but my manager wants me to experiment with the no-additional cost option of hosting NuGet packages on a shared network drive first.

Answer (score 0):

For your questions:

> I'm assuming that the modern architecture approach is to host this new
>   API wrapper class library as a NuGet package and then let each
>   application add a reference to it. Is this correct? Can you please
>   provide a url reference which describes the latest and greatest way to
>   set this up? I'm seeing different approaches described in google
>   search results.

Yes, manage the class library as nuget package is the most common way for this situation.

And there is no such document to summary different methods together.
Except manage the class library as a nuget package, you can also add the dlls, of the source code of the class library for other applications, but NuGet package is more efficient.

> Can you please provide a url reference which describes how to do this?
>   Are there any caveats or pitfalls with hosting a NuGet package on a
>   shared drive as opposed to using the VSTS "Package Management"
>   extension?

- To manage nuget packages in VSTS, you can refer the document [Get started with NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/get-started-nuget?view=vsts).
- To manage nuget packages in shared network, you can refer [Setting up Local NuGet feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds).

The only thing you need to notice is the **access permission**. If all the works are done inside the shared networt, then manage nuget packages in the shared network is ok. Else, if the nuget packages may be used outside of the shared network (such as use Hosted agent to build applications in VSTS), you'd better manage the nuget packages in VSTS feed.